# How do I implement removeable listeners when they're passed as lambdas or method references?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am wondering what may be a good way of implementing some kind of observable in Java without much interface-stuff.

I thought it would be nice to use the predefined functional interfaces. For this example, I use a `String` `Consumer` to represent a listener that takes a String for notification.

```
class Subject {

  List<Consumer<String>> listeners = new ArrayList<>();
  
  void addListener(Consumer<String> listener) { listeners.add(listener); }

  void removeListener(Consumer<String> listener { listeners.remove(listener); }

  ...
}

class PrintListener {
  public void print(String s) { System.out.println(s); }
}

Subject subject = new ...
PrintListener printListener = new ...
subject.add(printListener); // Works, I find it in the listener list
subject.remove(printListener); // Does NOT work. I still find it in the list
```

I found the explanation:

```
Consumer<String> a = printListener::print;
Consumer<String> b = printListener::print;

// it holds:
// a==b       : false
// a==a       : true
// a.equals(b): false
// a.equals(a): true
```

So I can't use lambdas/function pointers as they are.

There is always the alternative to have the good old interfaces back, s.t. we register object instances but not lambdas. But i hoped there is something more lightweight.

EDIT:

From current responses, I see the following approaches:

a) Return a `Handle` that holds the original reference
b) store the original reference yourself
c) Return some ID (integer) that can be used in `subject.remove()` instead of the original reference

I tend to like a). You still have to keep track of the `Handle`.

Comment: Did you mean `subject.addListener(printListener)` and `subject.removeListener(printListener)`? And does your code compile? `PrintListener` is not `Consumer<String>`...?

Comment: Related: [Is there a way to compare lambdas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095875/is-there-a-way-to-compare-lambdas)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm using rjxs quite often lately, and there they've used a custom return value called `Subscription` which can be called to remove the registered listener again. The same could be done in your case:

```java
public interface Subscription {
    void unsubscribe();
}
```

Then change your `addListener` method to this:

```java
public Subscription addListener(Consumer<String> listener) {
    listeners.add(listener);
    return () -> listeners.remove(listener);
}
```

The `removeListener` method can be removed entirely. And this can now be called like this:

```java
Subscription s = subject.addListener(printListener::print);
// later on when you want to remove the listener
s.unsubscribe();
```

This works, because the returned lambda in `addListener()` still uses the same reference of `listener` and thus can again be removed from the `List`.
Side note: it would probably make more sense to use a `Set` unless you really care about the iteration order of your `listeners`

A nice read would also be [Is there a way to compare lambdas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095875/is-there-a-way-to-compare-lambdas), which goes into more detail, why `printListener::print != printListener::print`.

Comment: One caveat: to make sure the unsubscribe doesn't remove the wrong listener (2 listeners may be equal, but with different identity), I think you'd wanna use something like an [identity hash set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48083029/identityset-identityhashset-use-identityhashmap) rather than the ArrayList that OP is currently using

Comment: I wrote an example just to double-check my logic https://ideone.com/K7bIJN and then this is with the fix https://ideone.com/UOPBvh You lose the guaranteed iteration order, but I would have thought most of the time that's not important. Also means you can't attach the same thing twice, which I would have thought is usually desirable, but I suppose it depends

Answer (score 6):

Your assumption is that each call to `printListener::print` returns the same instance of `print`.

```
Subject subject = new Subject();
PrintListener printListener= new PrintListener();
subject.add(printListener::print);
subject.remove(printListener::print);
```

The above code adds one listener, and tries to remove another listener, since `printListener::print.equals(printListener::print) == false`.

```
Subject subject = new Subject();
PrintListener printListener= new PrintListener();
Consumer<String> listener = printListener::print;
subject.add(listener);
subject.remove(listener);
```

The above works, requiring you to keep a reference to the listener if you need to remove it. Although if you wanted to keep it *very* lightweight, you could stick to only `Consumer`s without the concrete `PrintListener` class, if the implementations are very simple.

```
Consumer<String> listener = System.out::println;
subject.add(listener);
subject.remove(listener);
```

Answer (score 3):

You're right that relying on equality of functions becomes a bit janky.

The way I've sometimes solved this in the past is have the `add` method generate a random ID. The caller can use that same ID if it wants to remove the listener in future, or it can simply discard the ID if it never plans on removing the listener.

```
class Subject {
    Map<String, Consumer<String>> idToListener = new HashMap<>();
  
    // Returns the ID of the listener, use it to remove 
    String addListener(Consumer<String> listener) {
       String id = generateRandomId();
       idToListeners.put(id, listener);
       return id;
    }

    void removeListener(String id) { idToListener.remove(id); }
}
```

The `generateRandomId()` could be anything. It doesn't have to be complex. You could use consecutive integers if you want.

Comment: I believe OP has the opposite problem in that using the method reference `printListener::print` to define listeners already creates 2 distinct listener objects.

Answer (score 2):

For this to work, `PrintListener` needs to implement `Consumer<String>` since this is the required signature for a listener (as per your definition):

```
class PrintListener implements Consumer<String> {
    public void accept(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

To test it, you can implement a simple *notify*-methdod in the `Subject`:

```
void notify(String s) {
    listeners.forEach(listener -> listener.accept(s));
}
```

Now your code compiles and adding/removing the listener works as it should. To address the second part of your question, I added a listener using a lambda to demonstrate that this works just as well:

```
Subject subject = new Subject();

PrintListener printListener = new PrintListener();
Consumer<String> lambdaListener = System.out::println;

subject.addListener(printListener);
subject.addListener(lambdaListener);

subject.notify("abc");
subject.removeListener(printListener);
subject.removeListener(lambdaListener);
subject.notify("xyz");
```

The above outputs `abc` twice as expected.